# What's the best approach for producing a high-quality PDF from XML?

Tags: xml, pdf

I'm looking at creating a **high quality** PDF from an XML source, as the output of an online photobook creation tool.  There are literally hundreds of options for accomplishing this task from manual creation of the PDF (iText, PdfSharp etc) to PrinceXML to xsl-fo tools.  Here's some of the features I would like to support:

**Mandatory Support**

- Full Bleed PDFs
- Multi-Format Page Composition
- Support for dust jackets, spine printing, full wrap graphics + text
- Non-standard Page Dimensions
- Overlapping Graphical Elements
- Custom Fonts
- Cross Fold Layout Support – Double Page Spread
- 300-600dpi Image Support
- True WYSIWYG / reliable, predictable output (i.e. pixel perfect conversion from source material to PDF)
- Margin Control
- Colour Profile Embedding
- Unicode support
- Absolutely Positioned layout Elements

**Optional Support**

- Relative Layout Elements
- Images (CMYK, RGB)
- Fonts over HTTP
- Hyphenation Support
- Crop Marks Support
- Footnotes
- Spot Colour Fills
- Tabular Data Support
- Typesetting Support (Leading, Kerning, etc)

If anyone knows of the best way to accomplish this, I'd be very grateful.  Also, if anyone knows what other online photobook companies (such as Blurb or Shutterfly) use to convert an online book to a print-ready PDF I'd be very interested to know.

Comment: I was going to shout "LaTeX!" until I saw the WYSIWYG requirement.  If there *is* a program that fits all of these, I want to know too!

Comment: XML is a markup language. PDF is a presentation format. Unless you are wanting to render the raw XML source in PDF, it is impossible to answer your question without knowing what the XML describes.

Comment: @vocaro - the XML describes a photo book, so there will be nodes for pages, rich text sections, images etc

Comment: If you're thinking XSL-FO, XEP is probably your best bet. I don't quite understand the WYSIWYG requirement though.

Comment: What does "True WYSIWYG" mean? Are you looking for both an interactive editing application and an XML->PDF formatter?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've edited the question.  By "WYSIWYG" I mean that the PDF needs to be formatted very precisely.  If I convert the XML to an XHTML document, the PDF should be pixel-for-pixel identical to the source XHTML.

Comment: "If I convert the XML to an XHTML document" - by what rules would you do this? I mean, what standard would you be asking the XML-to-PDF rendering software package to adhere to? FYI, XHTML is not a pixel-anchored format; it is rendered by browsers depending on things like window width. So "pixel-for-pixel identical to the source XHTML" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @biziclop, this is from the wikipedia article on XSL-FO: "XSL-FO was specifically designed to meet the requirements of 'lightly designed' documents typified by technical manuals, business documents, invoices, and so on. While it can be and is used for more sophisticated designs, it is inherently limited in what it can do from a layout and typographic perspective."  I've not seen any examples that refute this, either.

Comment: @LarsH pixel-for-pixel across two ACID-compliant browsers should make sense.  I'm thinking we'd transform the XML to an XHTML document (that meets our required visual standard in, say, Chrome).  I'd then like to transform it to a PDF that is as close as possible to the source XHTML in every aspect.

Comment: @Paul, PDF is a paginated format, whereas XHTML is not. So again, I'm having trouble imagining how you can use an XHTML document as a visual standard for a PDF. You may want to consider generating (from your XML data, using XSLT) an Adobe InDesign or Design Standard document (they can use an XML format I believe). You could then open this in ID or DS, and manually tweak the layout to your liking.

Comment: @LarsH, agreed, but CSS2 does support selectors for page-based layouts (e.g. the @page rule) which we were planning to use.  With regard to your other suggestion, how would this work on a large scale as an automated process?

Comment: If you got your XSLT automatically generating InDesign documents whose layout you are really happy with, then I guess you could eliminate the manual tweaking, and have a large-scale automated process. But that seems like a big "if" to me. Anyway, I'm just greenlighting: I have not tried this myself.

Comment: @Paul Suart Nevertheless I have seen XEP used in professional publishing. They probably hadn't read Wikipedia so they didn't know it was impossible. :) XEP supports a lot of the features listed, like bleed areas and crop marks, advanced color spaces and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [**PrinceXML**](http://www.princexml.com/features/) (which name you list in your question, but don't tell us what you didn't like about it), which a few days ago I've mentioned [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/308357/a-better-wikipedia-page-to-pdf-tool/308542#308542) -- even with screenshots showing the results. [**Other samples of prince output**](http://www.princexml.com/samples/) is also around to look at.

However, what you mean with *"true WYSIWYG"* remains pretty obscure to me.

Because you'll have to show me an XML renderer first... one that would display me your XML on screen just like you expect your PDF pages to look like.

---

**Update:** Here is a set of examples for a PDF files created by PrinceXML. You can download 14 of them with this command on Linux or Mac OS X:

```
for i in 9-02 9-01 8-12 8-11 8-10 8-09 8-08 8-07 8-06 8-05 8-04 8-03 8-02 8-01; do 
   wget \
     -r \
     -t 3 \
     -l 1 \
     -c \
     -O AdvancedAquarist-200${i}.pdf \
      http://www.advancedaquarist.com/pdf/AdvancedAquarist-200${i}.pdf/at_download/file
done
```

On Windows:

```
for %i in (9-02 9-01 8-12 8-11 8-10 8-09 8-08 8-07 8-06 8-05 8-04 8-03 8-02 8-01) do ^ 
   wget.exe ^
     -r ^
     -t 3 ^
     -l 1 ^
     -c ^
     -O AdvancedAquarist-200%i.pdf ^
      http://www.advancedaquarist.com/pdf/AdvancedAquarist-200%i.pdf/at_download/file
```

IMHO, these are pretty complex layouts being produced here.

Note, that the older issues of this magazine, up to May 2008, were created with *iText 1.4.6* (according to their metadata).

The newer issues, from June 2008, were mostly done with *PrinceXML 6.0* (which is a release from 4 years ago...).

Nevertheless, both applications produced a very similar layout...

Comment: Thanks - we definitely *are* considering PrinceXML, I just didn't want to unduly influence any answers.  I still haven't seen an example Prince-rendered PDF that is a particularly complex layout.  If you know of any (over and above the samples page linked), I'd be grateful.

Comment: Just show me a *"particularly complex layout"* you've done in XML first. And I also think you owe an answer to my question about what you mean with *"true WYSIWYG"*...

Comment: @papitas.  None of the layouts exist yet.  We're doing discovery-phase work to assess the best options to convert an XML representation of a book into a printable PDF. 

By "WYSIWYG" I mean that the PDF needs to be formatted very precisely. If I convert the XML to an XHTML document, the PDF should be pixel-for-pixel identical to the source XHTML (when viewed in an ACID3-compliant browser), with page-breaks etc applied using the @page rule, and so on.

Comment: @Pual Saurt: PrinceXML is the best thing you can get when it comes to passing ACID tests for an XHTML->PDF converter. (And Hakon Wium Lie, who's one of the fathers of CSS, is also a director of the company which develops PrinceXML). About the limitations of PrinceXML see: http://www.princexml.com/doc/7.0/css21/. There must be a reason why Google decided in favor of PrinceXML to generate their PDF output from GoogleDocs...

Comment: @papitas: I didn't know Google use PrinceXML for googledocs.  I think we're now pretty certain we're going to use PrinceXML, so thanks for the additional info.

Comment: @Pual Saurt: You can check/verify yourself by exporting/downloading a GoogleDoc as PDF, and then check the file's metadata.

Answer (score -1):

You need to [translate the XML](http://www.xmlfiles.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) into HTML/XHTML, [style it as you want](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), and in a suitable browser, go to File>Print and, [with the right drivers set up](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), you can print to PDF.

Expecting a magic direct conversion is a big ask :-)

Comment: I'm not expecting a magic conversion.  I'd like a recommendation as to the best way to accomplish the task of transforming XML into a print-quality PDF.  Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't what I was looking for.